# Python list overlapping

Tags: python, list

How would you go about overlapping lists, without the boring and time consuming for-loops?

Functionality:

```
l1=[1,2,3]
l2=['a','b','c']
overlap(l1,l2) #[(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')]
overlap(l2,l1) #[('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)]
```

Comment: Strange use of the word "overlapping".

Comment: The correct term is "interleaving" in case you wonder.

Answer (score 7):

Use the built-in [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
>>> zip(l1,l2)
[(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')]

>>> zip(l2,l1)
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```